# Singular or plural after multiple noun adjuncts?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

After a series of noun adjuncts (attributive nouns), do we use the singular or plural form of the common final noun?

Example:

1. The bank lends to companies in power, steel, and textile industry.
2. The bank lends to companies in power, steel, and textile industries.

Comment: There have been a couple of downvotes. I'd appreciate if you add the reason when you downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plural.

Same as if you were to talk about the *tall and short people*, the three industries mentioned are separate entities.

Comment: I'd often use singular there: _Clothes for the short man and the tall man._ And adding the article seems necessary in OP also. The problem then is (when OP is not around to specify) whether to treat 'power' and 'steel' as stand-alone nouns or listed premodifiers ('the' before 'textile industry', or before  'power' with 'industries'?).

Comment: True, *the tall man and the short man* does work. However, OP was asking about *clothes for the tall and short man/men* (only 1 noun), and one man cannot be both tall and short.